# Event Handling with Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

The big picture is to have a `Thread t` print from `1` to a certain value and then pause execution depending on a `signal (ManualResetEvent)` during which another thread `s` executes. After `s` is done, it `sets the signal`. Hence, `T` resumes its execution.

```
class A
{
    int key;
    int temp;
    public A(int x)
    {
        key = x;
    }
    public EventHandler eventHandler;
    private void onKeyReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        eventHandler(this, e);
    }
    public int Temp
    {
        get { return temp; }
        set
        {
            if (value == temp) return;
            else if (temp == key)
                onKeyReached(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            else
                temp = value;
        }
    }
}
class Test
{
    static A a = new A(500);

    //signal to pause or resume threads
    static ManualResetEvent signal = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    static void Main()
    {
        a.eventHandler += WorkOnKeyReached;

        Thread t = new Thread(F);
        t.Start();
    }
    static void F()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            a.Temp = i;
            //when a.Temp == a.Key, a.OnkeyReached() is fired.
            signal.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine(a.Temp);
        }
    }
    static void WorkOnKeyReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        signal.Reset();
        Thread s = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing something else...");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("Done..");
            signal.Set();
        });
        s.Start();
    }
}
```

Program works as expected for the first half until Thread `t` pauses upon `signal` being `reset` in `WorkOnKeyReached`.
Yet after `WorkOnKeyReached` is done, I `set` the `signal` expect `t` to continue.

ouput:

```
1
2
..
500
Doing something else...
Done.
500
Doing something else...
Done.
```

Can anyone help explain this phenomenon? I'm just playing around with Threads and other things.

Comment: I can tell you right now the Temp setter against the A class is not thread safe

Comment: Why is `a.Temp = i` not safe? I understand only 1 thread executes that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int Temp
{
    get { return temp; }
    set
    {
        if (value == temp) return;
        else if (temp == key)
            onKeyReached(this, EventArgs.Empty);
       //else
            temp = value;
    }
}
```

Basically take out the else or it will never increment past 500